# Testing if the difference of the sum of two distributions is significative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test

I have two distributions and I wish to understand if the difference of the sum of the elements sampled from these distributions is significative or not.

I have set the problem this way:

I have $n_{x}$ extractions from $X \sim  N (\mu_{x}, \sigma_{x}^2)$
and $n_{y}$ extractions from $Y_{i} \sim  N (\mu_{y}, \sigma_{y}^2)$

the sum of the elements sampled from the two distributions are respectively: $ SUM_{x} \sim N(n_{x} \mu_{x},  n_{x} \sigma_{x}^2)$ and $ SUM_{y} \sim N(n_{y} \mu_{y},  n_{y} \sigma_{y}^2)$

Considering:
$$ \frac{(SUM_{x} - SUM_{y}) - (n_{x} \mu_{x} - n_{y} \mu_{y})} {\sqrt{n_{x} \sigma_{x} + n_{y} \sigma_{y}}} \sim N(0,1)$$

1. It is possible to use this formula to compare the sums of the elementes extracted from the two distributions as a Z-test?
2. When comparing the mean of two distributions with a low number of elements is usually used the t-test, how can I compare the two sums when the number of sampled elements is low ?

Comment: You seem to be assuming the samples from the two distributions are independent.  If your test is your null hypothesis (normal distributions with the known parameters as stated) is correct, then that is a possible test.  If your null hypothesis states the values of the means but not the variances then you might start exploring the $t$-test, though you will at least need a different denominator. If your null hypothesis is that the means are equal and you know nothing about the variances, you might want to look at Welch's $t$-test

Comment: @Henry The t-test is usually defined as a test of the mean using (among other elements) the mean of the sample and the standard error of the mean of the sample. If I substitute these elements with the sum of the sample and the standard error of the sum of the sample, it still be possible to use the t-distribution to perform the test ? The number of degree of freedoms  would still be n-1 ?